# how to select multiple line in log

Tags: awk, extract

I try to make file. It has all error message in particular log file.

This is log contents.

```
[ERROR] 2015-08-05 14:20:10 HandlerExceptionResolver -
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
.....
..e(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
..ractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
..Possible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
..Interceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)
..electOne(Unknown Source)
..emplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:163)
[INFO] 2015-08-05 14:20:39 LoggingInterceptor -  /products/430
```

and I try it

```
awk '$1 ~/^\[ERROR\]$/{print$0}' original.log > extract.log
```

but the result is only one line.

```
[ERROR] 2015-08-05 14:20:10 HandlerExceptionResolver -
```

my expected is..

```
[ERROR] 2015-08-05 14:20:10 HandlerExceptionResolver -
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
.....
..e(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
..ractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
..Possible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
..Interceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)
..electOne(Unknown Source)
..emplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:163)
```

I want to know how to extract all error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to turn printing off and on depending on the level you want to print:

```
$ cat log.awk
/^\[[A-Z]+\]/ { flag = 0 }
/^\[ERROR\]/ { flag = 1 }
flag

$ cat log.txt
[ERROR] 2015-08-05 14:20:10 HandlerExceptionResolver -enter code here
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:enter code here
.....enter code here
..e(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)enter code here
..ractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)enter code here
..Possible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)enter code here
..Interceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)enter code
..electOne(Unknown Source)enter code here
..emplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:163)enter code here
[INFO] 2015-08-05 14:20:39 LoggingInterceptor - /products/430
[ERROR] some other
multiline
error
[WARN] A warning not an error

$ awk -f log.awk log.txt
[ERROR] 2015-08-05 14:20:10 HandlerExceptionResolver -enter code here
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:enter code here
.....enter code here
..e(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)enter code here
..ractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)enter code here
..Possible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)enter code here
..Interceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)enter code
..electOne(Unknown Source)enter code here
..emplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:163)enter code here
[ERROR] some other
multiline
error
```

Comment: Good! it works well. thank you.  can i make  just one line command?